# Skimage random_noise : can't use "var" parameter

Tags: python, scikit-image

[Skimage documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.random_noise) includes a "var" parameter, but when I try to use it `noise_image = random_noise(image, mode=chosen_noise_mode, var=0.1)` I got the following error:

```
var keyword not in allowed keywords []
```

The error seems to make sense but it's on the documentation so i'm a bit confused. Can anyone help ?

reproducible example:

```
from skimage.util import random_noise

image = cv2.imread("my_image.jpg", flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# as skimage and cv2 have different encoding formats:
image = img_as_float(image)
noise_types=["pepper","poisson","speckle"]
chosen_noise_mode=noise_types[random.randint(0,2)]
noise_image = random_noise(image, mode=chosen_noise_mode, var=0.1, mean = 0)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. What is the value of `type` (which, btw, is a python built-in function and as such a bad name for a variable)?

Comment: @treuss thanks for pointing that type might have been the issue here, I was chosing mode randomly and thought it would just ignore var and mean if not gaussian or speckle. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want pass any/both of `var` then or `mean` your mode must be `'gaussian'`

```
random_noise(image, mode='gaussian', var=0.1)
```

*or*

```
# because mode is gaussian by default
random_noise(image, var=0.1)
```

if mode is not `'gaussian'` then don't pass any of var and mean

```
random_noise(image, mode=mode)
```

**Refrence:** [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.21.0/skimage/util/noise.py#L156-L168)

Comment: Still getting the error :/

`217 image = img_as_float(image)
--> 218 noise_image = random_noise(image, mode=type, var=0.1, mean = 0)

----
    160 for key in kwargs:
    161     if key not in allowedkwargs[allowedtypes[mode]]:
--> 162         raise ValueError('%s keyword not in allowed keywords %s' %
    163                          (key, allowedkwargs[allowedtypes[mode]]))
    165 # Set kwarg defaults
    166 for kw in allowedkwargs[allowedtypes[mode]]:

ValueError: var keyword not in allowed keywords []`

Comment: What is the value of the `type` variable that you are passing as the `mode` parameter?

Comment: @Bibhav thanks for pointing that out, I was chosing mode randomly and thought it would just ignore var and mean if not gaussian. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a valid value (like 'gaussian') for mode. Instead, you are passing the built-in function type.